# sdo_tune.quality_degradation returning negative values

Tags: oracle, spatial

While running the **sdo_tune.quality_degradation** function on one of our Oracle databases most of the results were around 1 but a number had values like -556127.225.

Does this mean that these indexes have suddenly become incredibly efficient and should return results before I finish typing the query?

I'm guessing it's a sign that something is wrong somewhere.

Any ideas?